# Download file from server showing save as dialog

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am facing the problem with downloading files from server (from browser). I have a link of the file and file name. Files can vary - they can be text files or something else.

This is not working any more - it just returns as empty file:

```
<a href="/resources/files/test.txt" download="">test.sql</a>
```

I am searching for answer for hours - why is this so hard to achieve? I am willing to do this with javascript action, just don't know how to implement?

Edit:
I don't receive any error - link to the file is correct. File returns empty. This is what I see in the browser:

[image]

**The solution was more than simple:**

Server side:

```
 public FileResult Download(string ImageName)
    {
        var FileVirtualPath = "~/App_Data/uploads/" + ImageName;
        return File(FileVirtualPath, "application/force-download", Path.GetFileName(FileVirtualPath));
    }
```

Client side: all that is needed is hyperlink for that action on the server.
Something like:

```
<a href='/Common/Download?ImageName=test.txt'>test.txt</a>
```

Comment: did you get any error messages anywhere?, did you try to debug the issue?

Comment: I've added explanation.

Comment: why your link file is text but it save as sql file?

Comment: it was just different example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution was more than simple:**

Server side:

```
 public FileResult Download(string ImageName)
    {
        var FileVirtualPath = "~/App_Data/uploads/" + ImageName;
        return File(FileVirtualPath, "application/force-download", Path.GetFileName(FileVirtualPath));
    }
```

Client side: all that is needed is hyperlink for that action on the server.
Something like:

```
<a href='/Common/Download?ImageName=test.txt'>test.txt</a>
```